# get lp job status using lpstat

Tags: ubuntu, cups

In ubuntu, I'd like to get the status of a print job using the command line.  When I send a job to the printer using lp, i can see the status of the print job in the taskbar applet.  For instance, I see a job that says "Pending" when I send a job to a printer that is off.

However, when I run lpstat -t, all I see is the following:

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: Brother_MFC-7340
device for BRFAX: usb:/dev/usb/lp0
device for Brother_MFC-7340: usb://Brother/MFC-7340?serial=000G9N299107
device for MFC-7340: usb://Brother/MFC-7340?serial=000G9N299107
device for MFC7340: usb://Brother/MFC-7340?serial=000G9N299107
BRFAX accepting requests since Tue 03 Dec 2013 10:42:29 AM CST
Brother_MFC-7340 accepting requests since Fri 06 Dec 2013 04:11:28 PM CST
MFC-7340 accepting requests since Fri 06 Dec 2013 04:11:28 PM CST
MFC7340 accepting requests since Fri 06 Dec 2013 04:11:28 PM CST
printer BRFAX is idle.  enabled since Tue 03 Dec 2013 10:42:29 AM CST
    File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/brfaxfilter" has insecure permissions (0100777/uid=0/gid=0).
printer Brother_MFC-7340 disabled since Fri 06 Dec 2013 04:11:28 PM CST -
    Unplugged or turned off
printer MFC-7340 disabled since Fri 06 Dec 2013 04:11:28 PM CST -
    Unplugged or turned off
printer MFC7340 disabled since Fri 06 Dec 2013 04:11:28 PM CST -
    Unplugged or turned off
Brother_MFC-7340-14     jnankin          77824   Tue 10 Dec 2013 06:46:52 PM CST
Brother_MFC-7340-15     jnankin         305152   Tue 10 Dec 2013 07:30:13 PM CST
```

How do I get lpstat to print "pending" or equivalent for this job?  Likewise, how do I see if a job completed or failed if I have the job string (in this case Brother_MFC-7340-15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
man lpstat
```

will show lots of things along with:

```
-t                    Prints all  status  information.  This
                      includes  all the information obtained
```

for the queue statused you could try to use:

```
 -W display the status of all print queues in wide format
```

OR

-p -l  will show long job listings.

Also "lpq" is useful for printer job queues information.

Comment: I had previously tried that, but -t doesn't really add anything useful about the jobs.  I have updated the question.  I get more information about the printers with -t, but nothing more detailed about the jobs (such as status).

Comment: why not discover some more options for lpstat?

Answer (score 0):

Well...

`lpstat -W completed` shows completed jobs.

`lpstat -W completed printerName` shows completed jobs for printer "printerName"

The lpstat command defaults to showing not-completed (pending) jobs...

*lpstat: Error - need "completed", "not-completed", or "all" after '-W' option!*

So there's a way to massage the command options to get what you need. Would it not be easier to just look at the local CUPS web interface at http://your.ip:631 - As that will provide more realtime status?

Comment: trying to do this programmatically with python